# Stackoverflow Exception при работе с JSON через Newtonsoft

Tags: c#, json

Имеются три функции и класс, которые связаны с этим вопросом:

- class Plane;
- function SavePlane;
- function ConvertToJson(функция отбрасывающая исключение);

### class Plane

```
class Plane
    {
        public string Number { get; set; }
        public string FlyDirection { get; set; }
        public string PlaneType { get; set; }
        public List<int> TheCountOfSits = new List<int>();
        public List<int> ThePriceForSit = new List<int>();
        public List<string> SitsUsability = new List<string>();

        public Plane() // EMPTY CONSTRUCTOR FOR SavePlane()
        {

        }
   }
```

### function SavePlane

```
public int SavePlane(string _number, string _flyDirection, string _planeType, int[] _sits, int[] _sitsPrice, string[] _sitsUsability, string _way)
        {
            if (!this.Identification_Status)
                return 0;
            else
            {
                
                Plane pl = new Plane(); // NEW PLANE OBJ FOR JSON CONVERTATION
                pl.Number = _number;
                pl.PlaneType = _flyDirection;
                pl.SitsUsability = _sitsUsability.Cast<string>().ToList();
                pl.TheCountOfSits = _sits.Cast<int>().ToList();
                pl.ThePriceForSit = _sitsPrice.Cast<int>().ToList();

                ConvertToJSON(pl); // FUNCTION WITH EXCEPTION
                return 1;

            }
        }
```

### Function ConvertToJson(Stackoverflow Exception)

```
        private static void ConvertToJSON(Plane id)
        {
            var js = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(id, Formatting.Indented);
        }
```

- При попытке сериализации через Newtonsoft выдается Stackoverflow Exception;
- С помощью быстрой проверки обнаруживается еще `CS0428: Не удается преобразовать группу методов "ConvertToJSON" в тип, не являющийся делегатом "object". Предполагалось вызывать этот метод?`;

При аналогичной реализации, но вся сериализация и присваивание происходят в main функции консольного приложения - ошибки нет. Я полнейший новичок в теме JSON, потому не могу решить подобное самостоятельно и надеюсь на вашу помощь. Из-за чего может происходить подобного рода ошибка в случае с JSON и как её устранять?

### ПОЛНЫЙ КОД ПРИЛОЖЕНИЯ

### Form1

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using AVIACompanyLib; // MY LIBRARY

namespace AviaProject_MPP4
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            HideSubPanels();
        }
     
        // НЕКОРРЕКТНОЕ РАСПОЛОЖЕНИЕ ДАННЫХ( ИСПРАВИТЬ )
        List<int> SitsCount = new List<int>();
        List<int> SitsPrices = new List<int>();
        List<string> SitsFree = new List<string>();
        string _way = "D:/projects/AVIACompanyLib/Test.json";
        Moderator_Class moderator_ = new Moderator_Class(); // AVIACompanyLib

        #region Design
        private void HideSubPanels()
        {
            SubPanel1.Visible = false;
        }

        private void HideSubPanel()
        {
            if (SubPanel1.Visible)
            {
                SubPanel1.Visible = false;
            }
        }

        private void ShowSubPanel(Panel _SubName)
        {
            if (!_SubName.Visible)
            {
                HideSubPanel();
                _SubName.Visible = true;
            }
            else
                _SubName.Visible = false;
        }

        private void User_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            ShowSubPanel(SubPanel1);
        }

        private void bunifuButton2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            LoadTXTTestPassword(); // LOAD TEST PASSSWORD FROM YOUR TXT FILE
        }

        private Form activeForm = null;
        private void OpenChildForm(Form _childForm) // OPEN NEW FORM
        {
            if (activeForm != null)
                activeForm.Close();
            activeForm = _childForm;
            _childForm.TopLevel = false;
            _childForm.FormBorderStyle = FormBorderStyle.None;
            _childForm.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
            ChildFormPanel.Controls.Add(_childForm);
            ChildFormPanel.Tag = _childForm;
            _childForm.BringToFront();
            _childForm.Show();
        }
        #endregion

        #region MyClassLibraryFunctions
        public void LoadTXTTestPassword()
        {
            moderator_.LoadPassword("D:/projects/AVIACompanyLib/Password.txt");
        }

        private void bunifuButton1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            moderator_.Identification(textBox1.Text);
        }

        private void SitsAndPrices(int _sits, int _price, string _nalichie) // FILL LISTS WITH USER'S INPUT FROM TEXTBOX
        {
            this.SitsCount.Add(_sits);
            this.SitsPrices.Add(_price);
            this.SitsFree.Add(_nalichie);
        }

        private void bunifuButton3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            int[] arr = this.SitsCount.ToArray();
            int[] arr2 = this.SitsPrices.ToArray();
            string[] arr3 = this.SitsFree.ToArray();
            moderator_.SavePlane("tst", "tst", "tst", arr, arr2, arr3, _way);
        }

        private void bunifuButton4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) // FILL LISTS WITH USER'S DATA
        {
            SitsAndPrices(Convert.ToInt32(textBox5.Text), Convert.ToInt32(textBox6.Text), textBox7.Text);
        }
        #endregion
    }
}
```

### clas Moderator_Class

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Text;
using System.Linq;
using System.Security.Cryptography;
using Newtonsoft.Json.Linq;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace AVIACompanyLib
{
    public class Moderator_Class
    {
        private string Password { get; set; }
        public bool Identification_Status = false;

        #region Identification reg
        public int Identification(string _password)
        {
            if (_password == this.Password)
            {
                this.Identification_Status = true; // THIS WILL LET RECOGNIZED USER WORK WITH OTHER FUNCTIONS
                return 1;
            }
            else
                return 0; // ACCESS DENIED
        }

        public Moderator_Class() // BARE CONSTRUCTOR
        {

        }

        public void LoadPassword(string _way)
        {
            using (File.OpenRead(_way))
            {
                this.Password = File.ReadLines(_way).Last(); // LOAD PASSWORD
            }
        }
        #endregion

        #region JSON work
        public int SavePlane(string _number, string _flyDirection, string _planeType, int[] _sits, int[] _sitsPrice, string[] _sitsUsability, string _way)
        {
            if (!this.Identification_Status)
                return 0;
            else
            {
                
                Plane pl = new Plane();
                pl.Number = _number;
                pl.PlaneType = _flyDirection;
                pl.SitsUsability = _sitsUsability.Cast<string>().ToList();
                pl.TheCountOfSits = _sits.Cast<int>().ToList();
                pl.ThePriceForSit = _sitsPrice.Cast<int>().ToList();
                ConvertToJSON(pl);
                return 1;

            }

        }

        private static void ConvertToJSON(Plane id)
        {
            var js = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(id, Formatting.Indented);
        }
        #endregion
    }
}
```

### class Plane

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;
using System.Linq;

namespace AVIACompanyLib
{
    class Plane
    {
        public string Number { get; set; }
        public string FlyDirection { get; set; }
        public string PlaneType { get; set; }
        public List<int> TheCountOfSits = new List<int>();
        public List<int> ThePriceForSit = new List<int>();
        public List<string> SitsUsability = new List<string>();

        public Plane() // EMPTY CONSTRUCTOR FOR SavePlane()
        {

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: В показанном коде не вижу причин для возникновения ошибки. Нужно больше кода.

Comment: @aepot тогда я залью весь полностью код в отдельной секции ниже нынешнего содержания.

Comment: Вы можете отредактировать вопрос и вставить код в него, не надо ничего создавать.

Comment: @aepot, залил код полностью

Answer (score 1, accepted):

На самом деле, я не знаю, в чём дело. Ошибку переполнения стека может вызвать рекурсия или внесение в него большого объема данных. Но ни того, не другого в показанном коде нет.

**UPD:** Исключение возникало не в C# коде а в момент резолва зависимой библиотеки (или в момент загрузки Newtonsoft.Json.dll в память). Мне удалось победить проблему, но только после того как я перенес основной проект на .NET Core 3.1, при этом подключенная своя бибилиотека осталась в исходном виде. Заставить  зависимости грузиться нормально на фреймворке мне не удалось.

---

Есть несколько минорных недочетов, но либо это не весь код, либо магия какая-то. Давайте поправим для начала минорные ошибки. Все списки в классе данных давайте сделаем свойствами, сейчас они поля, к тому же вы передаете в метод на сохранение массивы, сделанные из списков, так и давайте запишем в класс их массивами. Пустой конструктор можно выкинуть.

```cs
public class Plane
{
    public string Number { get; set; }
    public string FlyDirection { get; set; }
    public string PlaneType { get; set; }
    public int[] TheCountOfSits { get; set; }
    public int[] ThePriceForSit { get; set; }
    public string[] SitsUsability { get; set; }
}
```

Теперь можно упростить метод сохранения и исправить ошибку `pl.PlaneType = _flyDirection;`.

```cs
public int SavePlane(string _number, string _flyDirection, string _planeType, int[] _sits, int[] _sitsPrice, string[] _sitsUsability, string _way)
{
    if (!this.Identification_Status)
        return 0;
    Plane pl = new Plane
    {
        Number = _number,
        PlaneType = _planeType,
        FlyDirection = _flyDirection,
        SitsUsability = _sitsUsability,
        TheCountOfSits = _sits,
        ThePriceForSit = _sitsPrice
    };
    ConvertToJSON(pl);
    return 1;
}
```

Comment: Это полный код. Недочеты уже исправил, спасибо большое. Может ли это быть связано с тем, что Plane и Moderator_Class(где и происходит работа с JSON) являются библиотекой классов, которую я подключил к формам?

Comment: @JohnTheRipper8833 не помогло? А если класс `class Plane` сделать `public class Plane`?

Comment: @JohnTheRipper8833 пожмите оба проекта в архив, залейте на какой-нибудь онлайн-диск, дайте ссылку здесь в комментарии. Я попробую воспроизвести. Какая-то странная штуковина, а решение наверняка примитивное.

Comment: Первая версия до внесения правок, дабы было проще разобраться в проблеме. https://drive.google.com/file/d/1g1IFqRwuTmTJ4CanhtH2wSDo4mTxcAme/view?usp=sharing

Comment: @JohnTheRipper8833 воспроизвести я смог, но я не могу понять, в чем дело. ИСключение возникает не при вызове метода `Serialize`, а до него, то есть при входе в метод `ConvertToJSON` сразу происходит падение. Думаю в этот момент .NET пытается загрузить библиотеку `Newtonsoft.Json.dll` в память, но по необъяснимым причинам у него это не получается. Я попытаюсь еще покопаться, но пока идей, куда копать, по сути нет. Но можно сказать точно, что ваш C# код здесь не при чём, проблема где-то на низком уровне внутри дотнета.

Comment: спасибо Вам большое за помощь. Я отмечаю Ваш ответ как истинный

Comment: @JohnTheRipper8833 дополнил ответ. Пересоздайте основной проект на Winforms для .NET Core 3.1 или .NET 5. После переноса на новый .NET у меня все заработало. Альтернативно можете попробовать библиотеку сделать не под .NET Standard, а именно под ту же версию под .NET Framework. Другими словами, проблема была в совместимости подключенного Newtonsoft.Json к библиотеке .NET Standard при использовании ее из .NET Framework.